# Changing a value gradually for animation

Tags: javascript, math, animation

Let's suppose I have a variable `dimension` which I want to change from a value `a` to a value `b`.
`a` and `b` are integers and the first is major than the second.

To do this linearly I should do:

```
while (dimension < a)
dimension = dimension + 1
```

But what if I want it to grow exponentially? I totally suck at math and I can't figure this out. I was trying:

```
while (dimension < a)
dimension = dimension * dimension
```

the point is the value gets out of control almost immediately, it gets huge (way bigger than `a`)

Even if I try to use a huge scale (by setting `a` to a gigantic value) I can't get this done... And yet it seems [these guys](http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation) did it, and I think it should be easy too!

They also manage to do the same with all sorts of crazy equations all of which would be easily to me if only I were able to implement just one!

I just want a value to increase from 1 to 2 but gradually...

Hope someone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One extremely simple way to do it is to have a second counter that gets incremented by a smaller amount each iteration, and multiply it by the original counter to set it. Example, in your case:

```
step = 1.2;

while(dimension < a) {
    dimension = Math.max(dimension * step, a);
    step += 0.1;
}
```

Tweaking the values will probably be necessary to achieve the exact desired effect, but that's the general idea of it.
The call to Math.max will make sure that the value never goes over your goal.